# How to delete row if the previous have the same value in specific a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Let's say I have a table that looks something like this:

```
-------------------------------
id|column2|column3   |column4
-------------------------------
1  value1  somevalue  somevalue
2  value2  somevalue  somevalue
3  value2  somevalue  somevalue <----- I want this column deleted
4  value3  somevalue  somevalue
```

As you can see I want to delete the rows where the current and the previous row have the same value in column2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try something like

```
DELETE FROM Table t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Table t2 
              WHERE t1.Column2 = t2.Column2 
              AND t2.Id + 1 = t1.Id)
```

For your specific query, I would use the `t2.Id + 1 = t1.Id` instead of `t2.Id < t1.Id` as this would delete for any occurances, not consecutive entries only.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Table t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Table t2
              WHERE t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
              AND t1.Column3 = t2.Column3                  
              AND t1.Column4 = t2.Column4
              AND t2.Id > t1.Id)
```

OR if you need compare rows just by one field

```
DELETE FROM Table t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Table t2
              WHERE t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
              AND t2.Id > t1.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_name where rowid in(
select a.rowid 
from (
      select rowid,
            row_number() over (partition by column_name_having_duplicates order by                  column_name_having_duplicates)rnk 
from table_name a
)a
where a.rnk>1);
```